# I've got an error while i was installing a newest php

Tags: php, centos, update

I was updating the PHP version to the newest in my CentOS server, following [this guide](http://chrisjean.com/2011/06/24/upgrade-php-5-1-or-5-2-to-5-3-on-centos/) step by step.  When I finally get to install PHP, I get the following error.

```
sudo yum install php53 php53-cli php53-common php53-devel php53-gd
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Or just

```
yum install php53 php53-cli php53-common php53-devel php53-gd
-bash: yum: command not found
```

Can anyone help me?

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you what is wrong: You don't have the `sudo` command available.

Either the package is installed, but the binary is not in your `$PATH` variable, or you need to install it.

If you execute commands as the root user you don't need to run the command with `sudo`. You can use `sudo` to run as another user, specified with the `-u USERNAME` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now the problem is that yum is not found too....

Comment: @Joele25 `su -` to root and run `yum install sudo` again.

Comment: Yum and sudo commands dont works

Comment: @Joele25 Are you root? `su -` is not the same as `sudo`.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH` ?  You probably don't have these commands in your path.

Comment: [root@euve21750 ~]# echo $PATH
//sbin://bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: @jscott I'm root

Comment: @Joele25 please run `whoami` to make sure you're root. You could also try the absolute path for yum. If I remember correctly that is `/usr/bin/yum`

Comment: It said that i'm root.. and the directorty /usr/bin/yum doesnt exist

Comment: You can try `rpm -qa | grep -i yum` to see if yum is still installed or `whereis yum` and `which yum` to see if there is any path information on where the binary is installed.

Comment: [root@euve21750 ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i yum
yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-4.el5
[root@euve21750 ~]# whereis yum
yum:
[root@euve21750 ~]# which yum
/usr/bin/which: no yum in (//sbin://bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)


... so yum is installed but i can run it

Comment: Are you sure it is installed? It seems to me there is only the yum-metadata-parser package. The empty result of `whereis` support that suspicion. Please try to reinstall the yum package manually(download the package and then afterwards install it via rpm)

Comment: Please I'm a real dumbass of Centos can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Please use Google for those easy tasks the next time. There are extensive tutorials on how to do those basic tasks, like this [How to install yum on a Virtual Server](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver)

Comment: Ok, Thank you. But the question is how it is possible that i was running the yum command before and now i cant?